# Fading element on scroll with vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, css, css-transitions

I am creating element which fades in/out depending of scroll direction by adding css class.

But I'm having troubles doing that, scroll event doesn't get fired and I don't know why.

Also, I would like to avoid having large height element.

How can I make this?

JS:

```
var el = document.getElementById('el');

el.addEventListener('scroll', function(){
  //if scroll down -> fade out.
  //if scroll up -> fade in.
});
```

Css:

```
#el {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #00838f;
}

.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 1200px;
}

.fade-out {
    -webkit-animation: fadeOut .5s ease-in 1 forwards;
    animation: fadeOut .5s ease-in  1 forwards;
}

@keyframes fadeOut {
    to {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeOut {
    to {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class='container'>
   <div id="el"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: that el won't scroll - theres not enough content to cause an overflow.

Comment: What can I do except making #el overflow? Is this even possible with one small element on page?